# Proper MIME type for .woff2 fonts

Tags: fonts, mime-types, woff, woff2

Today I updated [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) package to 4.3.0 and noticed that **woff2** font was added. That file is linked in CSS so I need to configure nginx to serve woff2 files properly.

Currently I have this block in nginx config for fonts:

```
location ~* \.(otf|eot|woff|ttf)$ {
    types     {font/opentype otf;}
    types     {application/vnd.ms-fontobject eot;}
    types     {font/truetype ttf;}
    types     {application/font-woff woff;}
}
```

What is proper mime type for woff2 fonts?

Comment: Here's how to cache woff2 files in Apache: `<IfModule mod_mime.c> AddType font/woff2                      woff2` and `<IfModule mod_expires.c> ExpiresActive On           ExpiresByType font/woff2 "access plus 1 month"`. (Closing tags and newlines omitted.)

Answer (score 480, accepted):

In IIS you can declare the mime type for WOFF2 font files by adding the following to your project's web.config:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

**Update**:
The mime type may be changing according to the latest *W3C Editor's Draft WOFF2 spec*. See [Appendix A: Internet Media Type Registration](https://dev.w3.org/webfonts/WOFF2/spec/#IMT) section **6.5. WOFF 2.0** which states the latest ***proposed*** format is `font/woff2`

Comment: Now MIME-types in IIS 10 was support .woff2. With IIS 10 you don't need to change anything in web.config.

Comment: What purpose does the `<remove>` tag serve here? It doesn't seem to be documented in the IIS reference (https://www.iis.net/configreference)

Comment: @Pathogen Sometimes IIS throws an error if the mimeMap already exists.  Removing it before adding it fixes that error.

Comment: Appendix link is broken - please update it  :)

Answer (score 226):

`font/woff2`

For **nginx** add the following to the `mime.types` file:

`font/woff2    woff2;`

---

**Old Answer**

The mime type (sometime written as mimetype) for WOFF2 fonts has been **proposed** as `application/font-woff2`.

Also, if you refer to the spec (http://dev.w3.org/webfonts/WOFF2/spec/) you will see that `font/woff2` is being discussed. I suspect that the filal mime type for all fonts will eventually be the more logical `font/*` (`font/ttf`, `font/woff2` etc)...

N.B. WOFF2 is still in 'Working Draft' status -- not yet adopted officially.

Comment: This has been updated. The spec makes it very clear. Type is font and subtype is woff2 which makes is font/woff2. This is also what Google Fonts itself uses.

Comment: I still cannot see anything definitive in the spec. Though they do talk about wanting to introduce a `font/*` top level type. I think in the interests of full information, I will add that to my answer.

Comment: @atwright147 the mime types are covered in appendix A, for Woff2 it is section 6.5 of appendix A.

Comment: Updated March 2016: it is now a candidate recommendation and font/woff2 is the mimetype https://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF2/#IMT

Comment: when I gzip woff2 the file gets larger - unlike my CSS and JS files which are shrunk massively - maybe its already compressed?

Comment: @danday74 Yes, both woff and woff2 (and EOT) are already heavily compressed (unlike TTF and OTF) and should be omitted from any additional server-side compression. woff2 uses a different compression algorithm to woff and supposedly offers better compression rates.

Answer (score 41):

## Apache

In Apache, you can add the `woff2` mime type via your `.htaccess` file as stated by [this link](https://gist.github.com/sergejmueller/cf6b4f2133bcb3e2f64a).

```
AddType  application/font-woff2  .woff2
```

---

## IIS

In IIS, simply add the following `mimeMap` tag into your `web.config` file inside the `staticContent` tag.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
```

Comment: what about `application/x-font-woff2`

Comment: Hey @Moes :) Acutally, `application/x-font-woff2` is the old type for when woff2 was very new. The [W3C Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b) now recommends using `application/font-woff2` since that is widely supported. If you're after backwards compatibility, feel free to also include `x-font-woff2`.

Comment: In IIS, be careful to remove any previously defined extension entries in case they are defined somewhere else in the server. This will give you *very* confusing errors if you encounter it! `<remove fileExtension=".woff2" />` and then define it as above :)

Comment: Note that the proposed and also most probably be accepted is font/woff2

Comment: The [W3C Recommendation for WOFF File Format
2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF2/#IMT) *now* recommend using `font/woff2` as the MIME type but the [IANA list of official media
types](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) does not (yet) include WOFF2.

Answer (score 17):

http://dev.w3.org/webfonts/WOFF2/spec/#IMT

It seem that w3c switched it to `font/woff2`

I see there is some discussion about the proper mime type.
In the link we read:

> This document defines a **top-level** MIME type "font" ...
>
> ... the officially defined IANA subtypes such as "application/font-woff" ...
>
> The members of the W3C WebFonts WG believe the use of "application" top-level type is not ideal.

and later

```
6.5. WOFF 2.0

    Type name:

        font
    Subtype name:

        woff2
```

So proposition from W3C differs from IANA.

We can see that it also differs from woff type:
http://dev.w3.org/webfonts/WOFF/spec/#IMT
where we read:

```
Type name:

    application
Subtype name:

    font-woff
```

which is

```
application/font-woff
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/WOFF/#appendix-b

Comment: I don't see anything on that page to suggest that it has been changed to `font/woff2` can you calrify please?

Comment: Maybe I missunderstand it. I mean Appendix A, '6.5. WOFF 2.0'

Comment: I've got to say the spec isn't very clear. I think they are referring to the `font-woff2` part

Comment: Can't imagine that this is downvoted. The spec makes it very clear. Type is font and subtype is woff2 which makes is font/woff2. This is also what Google Fonts itself uses.

Comment: Agreed, can't see why this was downvoted. Though the spec document has been updated since this question was asked/answered.

Comment: I think this answer is better and also more correct, than the accepted. Also I think all fonts should come under one primary type name: "font/..."

Comment: I upvoted this initially but and thought I could get a blog post out of this. As it stands this post is inline with the WOFF2 spec but that is still a *Working Draft* and hasn't been moved to *Recommendation Status* yet. This means woff2 doesn't technically have a mime as the `font/woff2` is invalid until it's approved but the spec document has revoked the endorsement of `application/font-woff2` leaving us with no official one. Therefore I think at this point I'm going to use `application/font-woff2`.

Comment: @rtpHarry I previously upvoted both this answer and your comment. As of February 2017, the W3C published the *Standards Track* RFC 8081, making `font/woff2` the official media type. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/43321601/1640661