# Font-Awesome giving me an error in the browser console

Tags: css, nginx, fonts, font-awesome

I am getting this 3 errors

```
GET http://www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0 

GET http://www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0 

GET http://www.desktop.just4bettors.mobi/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0
```

I am configuring my NGINX for `Content-Security-Policy`, everything was working before, Font-Awesome was loading correctly until I set up the `Content-Security-Policy`, and this is what I have in that file

```
add_header Content-Security-Policy "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'
https://fonts.googleapis.com
https://fonts.gstatic.com
https://themes.googleusercontent.com
https://assets.zendesk.com;
font-src 'self' https://themes.googleusercontent.com
https://fonts.gstatic.com;";
```

Comment: those are technically not errors, that's just three GET requests without errors or network resolution data?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans and how can I fix it ?

Comment: I don't know? Until you add the actual error messages and browser warnings that you get to the post, there's not enough information to tell what your browser and server combined think is going wrong.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the info I post here is all I have. see the errors above, those 3 get errors are all I have so far.

Comment: The problem here is that "GET <url>" is not an error, it's just text. "GET" is the HTTP operation performed on the url, but there's no information on what the result of that GET was (200 = success. 404 = not found, 403 = forbidden, 500 = internal server error, etc). If there are CORS problems, the browser will actually tell you that if you have logging enabled, so do you have network and JS warnings and errors turned on in your console? If not, make sure it's all turned on and rerun it, to see whether you get more information. Also check the network tab to see what happens with those GET.

Comment: If it is a 404 error, see this post for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312063/font-awesome-error-404-on-fonts