# .woff2 failed to load in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iis, fonts, woff2

I got 404 errors for .woff files. Even though I have followed the instruction in [Proper MIME type for .woff2 fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235550/proper-mime-type-for-woff2-fonts) to add .woff to MIME types in IIS, I am still getting 404 errors.  It works in IE, but not in chrome. Any pointers?  I can not add this following to web.config.

```
 <system.web>
    ...
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.web>
```

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: what are we looking at? Because that XML is definitely not HTML, CSS and/or JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may have something to do with the IIS. My company is still using IIS 7.5. therefore woff2 is not supported by it.

Since neither IIS or web.config changes can solove the issue. I decide to use cdn such as https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto. It has instruction of how to use fonts there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mimeType="font/woff2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got ridden of these errors on a legacy server by adding within MIME-type in the IIS settings (intemgr) the extension woff2 with description application/x-font-woff2