# font-face doesn't work on hosting provider

Tags: html, css, font-face

I have problem when I am hosting a web site: before hosting when i run web site locally in my computer the font was fine, but when hosting it, font doesn't work. (I use font for pdf on my web page, and i use dompdf to convert to pdf)

Here the code:

```
        /* latin-ext */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Great Vibes';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 400;
          src: local('Great Vibes'), local('GreatVibes-Regular'), url(./asset/fonts/font-sertifikat/sertifikat.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
        }
        /* latin */
        @font-face {
          font-family: 'Great Vibes';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 400;
          src: local('Great Vibes'), local('GreatVibes-Regular'), url(./asset/fonts/font-sertifikat/sertifikat4.woff2) format('woff2');
          unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215;
        }



        p.serif {
            font-family: 'Great Vibes';
            font-size: 70px;
            padding-top: 250px;
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You probably do not have the fonts installed on the server but you do have them installed on your local machine.

Comment: @PeterM i have installed the font on the server.

Comment: Have you tried adding the font with the library? See https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/wiki/Features and https://github.com/PhenX/php-font-lib

Comment: have you checked the path `url(./asset/ ` ? try to put 1) complete 2) relative path and see what it does

Comment: @OldPadawan yeah i try it but it still doesn't work, i use this too <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes" rel="stylesheet"> but still doesn't work, but when i use on localy it's work fine.

Comment: @PeterM i don't understand hot to use that, can you give me an example?

Comment: what about `@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes');` on top of your CSS ? then `p.serif { font-family: 'Great Vibes'; }`

Comment: OldPadawan's option is probably easier :-)

Comment: @OldPadawan yeah i already do that, and it just work when i run localy but when i hosting it the font still doesn't work.

Comment: have you checked for errors in console ? where do you try calling the fonts ? in the HTML output that will be served to PDF or in the PDF settings ?

Comment: yes i have been checked, but nothing error :( i calling the font on html. this html will be convert on dompdf

Comment: there is only css here and the question does not support any of the other tags

Comment: if this is a path-related issue (for the php) and the CI tag, then check for errors. I can't see how client-side code would not work on any host/server/machine. Voting to close.

Comment: I think it's an http header issue, see my answer for details. But I agree most tags should be removed...

Answer (score 0):

The web server for your hosting provider does (probably) not send the correct `Content-Type` header for the fonts, and as a result your browser refuses to load them.

You [need proper content type headers for fonts to work](https://github.com/fontello/fontello/wiki/How-to-setup-server-to-serve-fonts).

Can you inspect the response headers for the .woff2 files in the 'Networking' tab of your browser's dev tools?

[image: devtools http headers]

If it's indeed missing (compare headers with local hosting), that's the problem. You need to get that server to insert http header `Content-Type: font/woff2`(*). And that will depend on your hosting provider. Maybe some will allow to do that in a `.htaccess` that you can install yourself in your site.

(*) edited: previous suggestion was `application/font-woff2`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28251873/6730571), there are many others on that topic.

Comment: i already inspect the response headers for the .woff2 files in the 'Networking' tab of my browser's, but i cann't find error

Comment: Don't look for an error. What is the value for `Content-Type` when it fails (hosted)? And what is the value when it works?

Comment: i cann't find content-type, i have been search on inpect in the 'Networking' tab of my browser's but i cann't find it

Comment: I added a working example from [google fonts page](https://fonts.google.com/). There must be a content-type header in the **Response Headers** section. What are the values you see, in both cases (working and not working) ?

Comment: I asked you twice to tell us what you see in both cases. You show us a screenshot of 1 case without specifiying which, and that screenshot shows references to fonts that are *not in your CSS*. You do not provide consistent details, so I will stop trying until I see meaningful/relevant/consistent info. I had that problem in the past, it was exactly as I described in my answer. Good luck.