# ASP.NET Core 2 MVC - Font-awesome woff/2 ttf not loading in production

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I'm building a personal project and having some issues with font-awesome webfonts not loading. i've made a gulp build to integrate Bootstrap 4 and building all my JS/SCSS/Fonts/Img from a src directory to a dist one. I serve Dist outside of wwwroot

When setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to Development, everything works right, my fonts load correctly but in "Production", it doesnt load and i get the following message in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)fa-regular-400.woff
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)fa-regular-400.woff2
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) fa-regular-400.ttf
```

When i mouseover the error i see that they are served from my SrcAssets not the DistAssets like all my other assets files.

I didnt found any working ressources regarding Core2.0 MVC everything i've found is regarding older stuff where these files extensions need to be mapped to for ex. application/font-woff2

Last thing i've tried was this below in the Configure method but it's still doesnt work.

```
FileExtensionContentTypeProvider typeProvider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

if (!typeProvider.Mappings.ContainsKey(".woff2"))
{
    typeProvider.Mappings.Add(".woff2", "application/font-woff2");
}
if (!typeProvider.Mappings.ContainsKey(".woff"))
{
    typeProvider.Mappings.Add(".woff", "application/font-woff");
}
if (!typeProvider.Mappings.ContainsKey(".ttf"))
{
    typeProvider.Mappings.Add(".woff", "application/font-ttf");
}

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = typeProvider,
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "DistAssets")),
    RequestPath = "/assets"
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I was have the same issue but I add `"../lib/FontAwesome/webfonts"` instead `"../webfonts"` in `_variables.scss`

```
$fa-font-path:                "../lib/FontAwesome/webfonts" !default;
```

Maybe it'll help you too :)

Answer (score 1):

Try add this code to your web.config

```
<configuration>
     ....
     <system.webServer>
         <staticContent>
             <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="font/woff" />
         </staticContent>
     </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue with .NET and found that it was Windows Server not allowing `*.woff2` files to be served correctly.
We followed [this guide](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/jan/25/fontawesome-fonts-and-mime-types-in-iis-and-other-web-servers) which we slightly adapted due to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955302/15291770) which states that the MIME type for `*.woff` and `*.woff2` files is now (more generally accepted) `font/woff` and `font/woff2` (and no longer, as the guide says, `application/font-woff`)

## From the guide

1. Open IIS Manager
   [image: IIS Manager with an arrow showing the MIME Types button]
   Open the "IIS Manager" at the top level (server level) and navigate to "MIME Types"
2. Set the MIME Type for both `.woff` and `.woff2` filetypes
   [image: Set the MIME Type value for woff and woff2 filetypes]
   Our server already had a value for `.woff` (which was `font/woff`), so we set a new value for `.woff2` to `font/woff2`
   **Note**: As per the [answer linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955302/15291770), the value set is `font/woff` and not `application/font-woff` as the MIME Type has been updated in the spec.

**Note**: The images above were copied from the [linked guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955302/15291770).

### You can also use the IIS command line tool appcmd like this:

```bash
c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd
             set config /
             section:staticContent /+
                         "[fileExtension=' .woff2 ',mimeType=' font/woff2']"
```

## No access to the global server:

Erik Parso's answer indicates (as does the [linked guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955302/15291770)), if you want to set this on your local server (or *have to* because you don't have access to the machine the web server is running on), then within the `web.config` file you should place the following:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="font/woff" />

    <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

This file will most likely be located at the top level of the .NET project and may also be called `Web.config` but will likely be an XML file.