# .WOFF2 fonts not being output to production

Tags: iis, teamcity, octopus-deploy, woff2

I'm in a .NET shop; Octopus and TeamCity are used for deploying to our testing and production environments. I added some .WOFF2 fonts to the `/_css/fonts folder`, and I'm referencing them as follows:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Roboto;
    src: url(/_css/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.eot);
    src: url(/_css/fonts/Roboto-Bold-webfont.woff2) format('woff2'), url(/_css/fonts/roboto-bold-webfont.woff), <!-- other fallback fonts -->
```

The .WOFF2 fonts appear on localhost, but somehow they are being omitted from the build output. What's weird is there is a reference to a .WOFF2 of FontAwesome that is successfully being output. I've checked the properties of the fonts in Visual Studio, and all the new (non-outputting) fonts are set to Copy Always to output directory. Despite all our efforts, we keep getting 404 errors for those fonts.

TIA for any help you can provide!

Comment: Are you hosting your application on IIS? If yes, this might be configuration problem. By default IIS is not accepting woff2 mime type. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28955302/7225096

Comment: OK, I must have been using an old MIME type; I had it as `application/font-woff2`. I'll make that change and see how it goes.

Comment: Can you publish (release build) somewhere locally and check the files were included in the build? Or double check the files have actually been copied to the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **MIME** type inside the IIS Manager.

1. Open the "MIME types" in your server Home page (or Home page of your specific
2. Add ".woff2" with MIME type "font/woff2".

[image]

In my case it works with IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to add IIS a MIME-TYPE for woff2. You can configure it in web.config**

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

**And you can also do this through IIS manager.**

1. Open the `MIME Types`
2. Add `.woff2` with MIME type as `application/x-font-woff` as well.