# GET https://site.azurewebsites.net/fa-solid-900.f0..d.woff2 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, azure, font-awesome-5

I use Font Awesome in angular app, it works fine but when deploying, this error is appear in console

`GET https://site.azurewebsites.net/fa-solid-900.f093864079d44808c60d.woff2 404 (Not Found)`

I import fontawesome in style.scss

`"styles": [
             "src/styles.scss",
             "src/assets/css/fontawesome-all.min.css"
           ],`

here is assets

[assets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GaX0.png)

there is no error in local, only after deploying it, even it's found in dist folder, Should I import them in other way?

Comment: Add woff2 mime type to your web.config See also https://ppolyzos.com/2016/03/16/mime-types-missing-in-azure-websites/

Comment: Actually I don't have web.config in my files @yurzui

Comment: You can create it and include in your assets

Comment: I'm not sure if it will have any effects on the site, What do you think? @yurzui

Comment: I've added web.config and no errors in console. Thanks! @yurzui

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proper MIME type for .woff2 fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235550/proper-mime-type-for-woff2-fonts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's solved by adding woff2 mime type to web.config
as mentioned  [ppolyzos.com/2016/03/16/mime-types-missing-in-azure-websites](https://ppolyzos.com/2016/03/16/mime-types-missing-in-azure-websites)

Comment: I suggest use absolute path/url in font awesome css files with fonts references, instead relative path

Answer (score -3):

Try checking in [Kudu](https://www.jamessturtevant.com/posts/How-to-add-edit-and-remove-files-in-your-azure-webapp-using-the-kudu-service-dashboard/) console and check if it is present on the deployed server.

https://site.scm.azurewebsites.net/fa-solid-900.f093864079d44808c60d.woff2

Comment: I've check it ant I found them in files, it's solved by adding mime type to  web.config